# API for HTTP Proxy

Tags: proxy, fiddler, charles-proxy

I have been using Charles Proxy and Fiddles as tools, but now I want to embed them in my java code. Is their any other tool present that exposes API to do throttling, or simulate 3G/4G speed etc.

Thanks,

Comment: Fiddler exposes its base proxy implementation as the FiddlerCore class library, but it's written for .NET, not Java.